# Positioning checkmark from JQuery Validation

Tags: css, positioning

[Site here.](http://www.ipalaces.org/hosting/register.php)

If you notice, the checkmarks are align with the table. I want the checkmark next to the port to be just right of it, not all the way aligned to the right as it shows.

Edit:
Here is a picture showing what i'd like.
[image]

Comment: I've just realized that you were talking about the checkbox not the checkmarks... im right?

Comment: No the checkmarks. I will attach a pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tested, but in your validator you got this:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.is(":radio")) error.appendTo(element.parent().next().next());
    else if (element.is(":checkbox")) error.appendTo(element.next());
    else error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
```

you can add:

```
 else if (element.is("#Port")) error.appendTo(element.next());
```

So it will look like:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.is(":radio")) error.appendTo(element.parent().next().next());
    else if (element.is(":checkbox")) error.appendTo(element.next());
    else if (element.is("#Port")) error.appendTo(element.next());
    else error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
```

Comment: This works if I use element.parent() rather than element.next()

Thanks, didn't think about going to the source of the problem.